# Java i18n: use one ResourceBundle accessor per package, or one for whole project?

Tags: java, internationalization, resourcebundle

I don't know anything about internationalization.

I have a project with several packages. I am using Eclipse's built-in "Externalize Strings" wizard to extract String constants in my classes to a properties file and replace those Strings with calls to a static accessor. So instead of

```
System.out.println("Hello, world!");
```

I end up with

```
System.out.println(Messages.getString("MyKey"));
```

and a `Messages` utility class in every package (which provides a static `getString` method for getting the desired String from a ResourceBundle [in this case a `.properties` file]). Is it best to have a `Messages` class in every package, or have a single `Messages` class for the entire project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm in favor of a global localization file.  You will have duplicate keys ("OK", "Cancel") which would require duplication or nesting, and interfacing with outside localization people is easier if the resources are consolidated.

Comment: The fewer the files, the better. Consolidating shared strings, as Michael said, into a single file promotes translation consistency. And it's easier to fix bugs if you only have to look for them in a few files.

Comment: OK- you're asking about the Messages class...Then one per package.

Comment: @Mike--Why have more classes than resource files?

Comment: So you suggest a single resource file with all translatable strings from all packages and a single "Messages" class, say in package "org.mypackage.i18n"?

Comment: That's what I do.  I worked with one codebase that worked the opposite way (multiple resource files and multiple classes) and didn't like it.  Interested to know if some see a clear advantage to multiple classes.

Answer (score 3):

I would keep one-per-package. This way maintenance/refactoring/unit-testing is much easier.

Also, there are no global dependencies on a single file.