# Is there a good alternative to gettext _() method in Java?

Tags: java, gettext

It is a common way to decouple text messages and source code in C/Python/PHP/etc by means of [gettext](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/) set of utilities. I'm trying to do something similar in my Java project, according to [this instruction](http://www.gnu.org/software/hello/manual/gettext/Java.html). Is it the best possible way? Or I should try something different and more advanced?

ps. I would like to avoid complex initialization and ideally my Java code should look like:

```
[...]
public String howBigIsTheFile(File f) {
  String name = f.getAbsolutePath();
  long length = f.length();
  return _("The file %s is %d bytes long", name, length);
}
```

Something like [gettext-commons](http://code.google.com/p/gettext-commons/wiki/Tutorial) maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume this question is about **stand-alone application** (command-line, SWING, etc) and not about server-side application (with multiple users accessing concurrently).

In stand-alone application, the easiest is to create a **single static accessor class** that would be responsible for loading a **single resource bundle** and then looking up strings in that resource bundle.

Something like this:

```
public class ResourceUtil {

    private static ResourceBundle rb;

    static {
        //set the default locale
        setLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
    }

    public static void setLocale(Locale locale) {
        rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("Resources", locale);
    }

    public static String tr(String key, Object... args) {
        return MessageFormat.format(rb.getString(key), args);
    }

}
```

You can change the active locale with `setLocale(Locale)` method and access translated strings with `tr(String,Object...)` method.

Then, you could call it from your class like this:

```
import static ResourceUtil.tr;

public String howBigIsTheFile(File f) {
  String name = f.getAbsolutePath();
  long length = f.length();
  return tr("The file %s is %d bytes long", name, length);
}
```

Notice the static import.

**Disclaimer**: all provided code is on pseudo-code level and is not guaranteed to compile.

Depending on the size of your application, you might find it useful to use **IDE string externalization support** (e.g. see chapter in [Eclipse JDT help](http://help.eclipse.org/help33/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/concepts/cnls.htm), I'm sure other IDEs have some similar features).

You could also use several resource bundles and/or several static classes - it depends on the size of your application and your personal preference. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067336/java-i18n-use-one-resourcebundle-accessor-per-package-or-one-for-whole-project) for further debate about this.

In a server-environment using static approach like above would lead into issues as different users would have different locales. Depending on your webapp framework, you would solve this issue differently (e.g. [use MessageSource in Spring](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#context-functionality-messagesource)).

Answer (score 0):

If you think about I18N/L10N, Java has its own mechanism here: the properties file. You can see an example [in the internationalization tutorials](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/resbundle/propfile.html). It's even simpler than gettext stuff :).

Comment: With this standard Java approach I have to load `ResourceBundle` myself before I do anything with the text. See the code in the question (just updated). This is the simplicity I'm after.

Comment: Besides proposition of initialization of ResourceBundle in static area of Main class, I'm not aware of anything else. I believe this is a good question then.

Comment: Yes, you load the resource bundle before you use it.  It seems likely that any application you develop will have code that perform initialization.  Loading the ResourceBundle is part of initialization.